# custom interface cocoa xcode 4

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface, interface-builder

how can i create custom interfaces in xcode 4? i've seen programs like Kaleidoscope (http://designshack.co.uk/images/designs/kaleidoscope-for-mac.jpg) using custom controls or something not available for drag and drop on xode.

any help? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll get better help if you take the time to [craft more specific questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Since you're speaking generally, I'll answer generally: Xcode 4 will not help you create custom interfaces (at least not beyond letting you edit the code to build them). This is done entirely in code.

Learn to [draw with Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) then learn how controls and cells work, then ask specific questions when you don't understand.